# Traverse knockout to root from outside view model hierarchy scope

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

If I'm outside the context of a knockout object hierarchy (like in a globally referenced common class), is it possible to

1. determine if an overall root view model exists (in other words, determine if applyBindings was called for the current view)?
2. if it exists, locate the overall root view model of the view I'm currently on?

Does anyone know of any utils or extensions that do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to look at using `ko.dataFor` and/or `ko.contextFor`, as described here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html

Given an element, they will tell you the data or context ($data, $root, $parent, $parents) that would be available for binding at that level.